# Apache HTTPS configuration for Node.js Express app

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, https, apache2

I have https Node.js express server with valid certificates. I'am running this server on my_server_ip:8443 and I need to make it https://example.com (example.com:443).

My app.js

```
var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('/home/example.com/ssl.key', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('/home/example.com/ssl.cert', 'utf8');
var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};

var server = https.createServer(credentials, app);
```

My apache conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  SuexecUserGroup #1003 #1004
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com
  DocumentRoot /home/example.com/public_html

  ErrorLog /var/log/virtualmin/example.com_error_log
  CustomLog /var/log/virtualmin/example.com_access_log combined

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /home/example.com/ssl.cert
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/example.com/ssl.key
  SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1

  <Proxy *>
          Order deny,allow
          Allow from all
  </Proxy>
  <Location />
        ProxyPass https://localhost:8443/
        ProxyPassReverse https://localhost:8443/
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

I am getting **500 Internal Server Error** when I open https://example.com

EDIT: I see where is problem maybe. For some reason Apache looking into *:80 configuration instead of *:443 configuration. Why?

Comment: `503` means that there is problem in connectivity with upstream component.  Are you able to access `node.js` server at port `3000` ?

Comment: I am able to access node.js on every port. Server running fine

Comment: `ProxyPass https://localhost:3000/` points to node.js server running at port 3000, but I think your node.js server is running at port 8443 (you have mentioned in starting).

Comment: Ah yes sorry its my fault. So I am not getting 503 but 500. Post edited.

Comment: @MukeshSharma I see where is problem. For some reason Apache looking into *:80 configuration instead of *:443. Why?

Comment: probably, you are hitting `http` instead of `https` scheme.

Comment: Yes, All other 5 websites hitting https config file as they are supposted, but this website not.